# How to pipe response from nodejs fetch response to an express response

Tags: node.js, express, fetch, node-streams

I want to pipe response from nodejs fetch request to an express response, the same way it was posible with node-fetch modules

```
const fetchResponse = awair fetch(myUrl);
fetchResponse.body.pipe(expressResponse);
```

Comment: What's the issue? Show the debugging details

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's been 4 months, so I hope you found an answer already. I believe that this is you were looking for:

```
const { Readable } = require( "stream" );
// or maybe you'd prefer
// import { Readable } from "stream";

/* Insert code here. */

...

const fetchResponse = await fetch(myUrl); 
Readable.fromWeb( fetchResponse.body ).pipe( expressResponse );
```

The [Readable.fromWeb()](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#streamreadablefromwebreadablestream-options) method will give you the Stream.Readable that you're looking for.

The "problem" you're running into is that the Node.js version of fetch being standard-compliant. Theoretically this is a good thing, because you should know what you're going to get.

It introduced a new Stream standard into Node.js. You're probably already with the Streams library's Readable and FS.ReadStream. It may feel like a bait and switch, but in moving from the standardish *node-fetch* to the fully compliant *fetch* you've been awkwardly introduced to the also standard-compliant ReadableStream.  This new stream implementation doesn't have the pipe() method that you're used to, but instead it has pipeThrough() and pipeTo().

Standards References:

- [fetch](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/)
- [Web Streams](https://streams.spec.whatwg.org/)

Comment: Thank you! This is quite confusing, and it was hard to come across a good explanation.
Unfortunately, Readable.fromWeb() is still flagged as experimental in Node 20.

Answer (score 0):

very interesting， I think you probably want to do it like this

```
import express from 'express';
import fetch from 'node-fetch';

const app = express();
const PORT = 3000;

app.get('/proxy', async (req, res) => {
  const url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76958222/how-to-pipe-response-from-nodejs-fetch-response-to-an-express-response'; // Replace with your URL

    const fetchResponse = await fetch(url);
    console.log('Response received' + fetchResponse.body);
    fetchResponse.body.pipe(res);
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

and then you can use http://127.0.0.1:3000/proxy to visit the url

Comment: This is our current implementation, we want to remove the use of external dependencies,  so neither axios or node-fetch will do for us, we want native node module to do the trick. I can always use http module, but I was wandering of it is going to be easier with node native fetch

Answer (score -1):

If you decide to use axios instead of the native fetch, you can still achieve this by directly streaming the response using the stream feature.

Here's how you can do it with axios:

**First, install axios:**

```
npm install axios
```

**Use axios to make a request and pipe the response:**

```
const express = require('express');
const axios = require('axios');

const app = express();

app.get('/proxy', async (req, res) => {
    const url = 'YOUR_TARGET_URL_HERE';

    // Axios request with responseType set to 'stream'
    const response = await axios.get(url, { responseType: 'stream' });
    
    // Set the headers from the original response, if needed
    res.set(response.headers);

    // Pipe the Axios response stream directly to the Express response
    response.data.pipe(res);
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Server started on http://localhost:3000');
});
```

I hope this give you an idea.